# How do I write my time conversion function to account for places after the decimal point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, format, duration

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have this function for converting a string (meant to represent a time duration) into milliseconds …

```
  def duration_in_milliseconds(input)
    if input
      input.split(':').map(&:to_i).inject(0) { |a, b| a * 60 + b } * 1000
    else
      0
    end
  end
```

Problem is, the above doesn’t take account over if there are tenths of a second (a decimal place). So passing this argument “19:14.1” gets the same result as passing this argument “19:14”.  How can I make adjustments to the above so that it will account for the part of the duration after the decimal place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert it to Float while processing instead of Integer:

```
  def duration_in_milliseconds(input)
    if input
      input.split(':').map(&:to_f).inject(0) { |a, b| a * 60 + b } * 1000
    else
      0
    end
  end

duration_in_milliseconds('19:14')
#=> 1154000.0
duration_in_milliseconds('19:14.1')
#=> 1154100.0
```